# Convert an int to Hex and check the assertion. Java AT

Tags: java, testing, automation, integer, hex

I have a task to write an @Test annotated method which uses Integer toHexString and asserts that 11 becomes b

This is how I tried this getting illegal start of expression:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class HexTest {
    @Test
    public static void main (String[] args){
        static Integer.toHexString(11){
            Assert.assertEquals("int to Hex", 'b', 11);
        }
    }
}
```

I would be so grateful if someone could tell me what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: What is `static Integer.toHexString(11){` supposed to be? Also, `Assert.assertEquals("int to Hex", 'b', 11);` will check if 11 is equal to 'b', which it isn't, so your test will never pass. You are supposed to call the method you want to test passing to it the value you want to convert as a parameter, store the result of the conversion in a variable, and check that this variable is equal to your expected result.

Comment: 1)static Integer.toHexString(11) It's supposed to be the calling of the method of Integer - toHexString.  How should it be called correctly?  2) It is a task from a book for testers - check if 11 is equal to 'b' - to understand static methods and Integer.

Comment: You don't need the `static` keyword to call a static method. I have provided an answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks! I got the syntax problem off, the code is correct. Though I don't understand how i got 98 in expected and what do I have to do to get 11 to hex                                                                              java.lang.AssertionError: int to Hex 
Expected :98
Actual   :11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

```java
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class HexTest {
    @Test
    public void integerToHexStringTest() { // test method definition
        // GIVEN
        String expected = "b";
        
        // WHEN 
        String actual = Integer.toHexString(11); // call method `toHexString(11)`

        // THEN
        Assert.assertEquals("int to Hex", expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't need the `static` keyword to call a static method. What you should be doing is calling the method, storing the result in a variable and checking if that variable holds the value you expect:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class HexTest {
    @Test
    public void testToHexString(){
        String result = Integer.toHexString(11);
        Assert.assertEquals("int to Hex", "b", result);
    }
}
```